# Change CSS values based on user selection

Tags: css

I have a dynamic web-app using MySQL, PHP, jQuery, JavaScript and Twitter Bootstrap.

I've created a few color theme options for the users, but I'd like to offer them the ability to setup their own color schemes. I'm not entirely sure of the best way to go about this.

I'm guessing I would allow the users to save the key colors into a database table and use a generic CSS file where I can replace the values. But I'm not sure how to do the last part of that.

How would I write into the CSS file replacing "tokens" or variables, before it's loaded by the website? Or should I use jQuery to replace the CSS at runtime?

Thanks

Comment: Clearly, colors are variables here. So, maintain generic class names representing the type of color. For example, `safe--color` (_representing positive action like clicking on `confirm` button_) and `unsafe--color` like for `delete` button. Keep all these color based classes in a color css file like `color-<theme-name>.css`. These color classes will differ based on selected theme from backend.

Comment: Looks like you want http://lesscss.org/

Comment: Worth looking into CSS variables http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-variables

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll look into all your suggestions.